# VBA - How to use worksheet and range variables together?

Tags: excel, vba, variables

```
Sub ex()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Dim ws As Worksheet: Dim var As Range
    Set wb = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    'usually do this
    Set var = ws.Cells(1, 1)
    var = 5
    
    'want to do this but how?
    Set var = Cells(1, 1)
    ws.var = 5
    
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no need for that, as `var` is already defined as being part of `ws` after you `Set` it. The real question is, why would you want to? `Cells` with no sheet specified is assumed to be part of `ActiveSheet`

Comment: You can't really do that...   One question wuold be *why* do you want to do that?  What problem would that solve for you?

Comment: Thank you braX you got there before I could fix it.

Comment: Thought it might be nice when working across worksheets to have several range variables    and wrksh variables that I could intermingle.

Comment: Then `ws.Range(var.Address) = 5` would work but you may as well declare `var` as string,  assign "A1" as its value, and use `ws.Range(var)`